# Android gradle build system - Filtering resources

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I need help for resource filtering in android application with new gradle build system.

This is my build.gradle: https://gist.github.com/fjtorres/5593683

I have created new task for filtering resources but not sure how to join this task to build system.

Thanks and regards.